# Incrementing score through an observer pattern in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently plan to have a score system which increments the score variable by 1 when the OnDeath action is called. Unfortunately, I'm stumped when it comes to the actual incrementation part and have only made it to the part where I invoke '1' into the OnDeath action (which just updates the displayed score count as '1' only).

Here's the Enemy class where I implement the OnDeath observer pattern.

```
public class EnemyOne : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static event Action<int> OnDeath;

    public float speed;
    public int health;
    private Transform waypoint;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public UIManager um;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        BulletController.onHit += Damage;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        
        waypoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Waypoint").GetComponent<Transform>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    /*void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Bullet"))
        {
            health--;
        }
    }
    */

    public void Damage(GameObject collided, int damage)
    {
        if (collided == this.gameObject)
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        health -= damage;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoint.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    void Death()
    {
        OnDeath?.Invoke(1);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        BulletController.onHit -= Damage;
    }
}
```

And here's where I re-call said pattern through the UIManager to update the score.

```
public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI txt;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        EnemyOne.OnDeath += UpdateScore;
    }

    public void UpdateScore(int score)
    {
        txt.text = score.ToString();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        EnemyOne.OnDeath -= UpdateScore;
    }
}
```

How should I work around this problem? Thanks for the help to whoever sees this!

Comment: Where is this `score` value that you actually wanted to update? Either keep that in UIManager, and when `UpdateScore` of `UIManager` gets called, simply `decrement` the received value from this `UIManager` field and then update the `text` value.

Comment: @nIcEcOw hey there, thanks for helping me out! please ignore how clueless this may sound of me but would I be updating the text value through the UpdateScore function or through a separate function (eg: void Update)?

Comment: Updating a text value via `Update` sounds a bit demanding, when you are listening for a change via an Action, so only updating it when event fires is a way to go, like you have already implemented. I prefer to create a `ScriptableObject` of the value, which is to be updated by someone and needed by someone for display purposes. So that they remain in Sync and without much coupling between them.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's (as usual) a question of responsibility. Who should keep track of the count?

In my opinion probably the one invoking that event ;)

*Except you have a more general central "manager" that would consume the `EnemyOne.OnDeath` event, increase the counter and then forward it to everyone.*

In your case you can simply add the counter directly

```c#
public static int deathCount;
public static event Action<int> OnDeath;
```

and instead pass in

```c#
deathCount++;
OnDeath?.Invoke(deathCount);
```

or also directly (though not as good for debugging)

```c#
// Here the order is important
// the prefix ++ first increments the value then passes it on
// a trailing ++ would instead pass in the current value and then increment it
OnDeath?.Invoke(++deathCount);
```

---

In general if you go through the event anyway then why do you also reference the

```c#
public UIManager um;
```

directly? Then the whole pattern makes not much sense. If you anyway already know the reference you can as well call the method directly.

Comment: total lifesaver, that’s what you are! I was trying to implement the same ++deathCounter increment variable but instead of keeping track of it with a new counter, I incremented it using my original score variable (totally foolish of me). Thank you so much!